# Forming find conditions from multi word search query in CakePHP

Tags: search, cakephp

I have products with multiple fields than can be searched (name, text, product code, etc).

What I want to do is explode the search string and make sure that every word is found somewhere at the record.

With one word I would normally do like:

```
'OR'=>array(
    'name LIKE'=>'%' . $oneword . '%',
    'text LIKE'=>'%' . $oneword . '%',
    'code LIKE'=>'%' . $oneword . '%',
 )
```

Now I feel that I have to make as many OR-arrays as search string has words and include them all in AND-array. I just don't know how to code it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```
$conditions = array();
$search_terms = explode(' ', $search_string);
foreach($search_terms as $search_term){
    $conditions[] = array('Model.name Like' =>'%'.$search_term.'%');
    $conditions[] = array('Model.text Like' =>'%'.$search_term.'%');
    $conditions[] = array('Model.code Like' =>'%'.$search_term.'%');
}
$products = $this->paginate('Product', array('conditions' => array('OR' => $conditions)));
```

Edit: If all your search term must be present in any of the fields, it would be something like this:

```
$conditions = array();
$search_terms = explode(' ', $search_string);
foreach($search_terms as $search_term){
    $conditions[] = array('OR' => array('Model.name Like' =>'%'.$search_term.'%',
                                        'Model.text Like' =>'%'.$search_term.'%',
                                        'Model.code Like' =>'%'.$search_term.'%',
                                  )
                          );
}
$products = $this->paginate('Product', $conditions);
```

Comment: But this code won't require all search terms to be present on record as far as I understand this...

Comment: explode() should point you to the right direction. I think the answer is pretty obvious already.

Comment: @Henri, I guess I didn't understood what you wanted at first. Check my update

Comment: Answer is obvius but it won't do what I want. Now any of the search terms would return a record. But I wan't **all of them** to be present in **any of the fields**. I'm sorry not to be clear enough.

Comment: @Henri, maybe you're clear and I don't understand. What my code do is: (term1 must be in field1 or field2 or fieldN) AND (term2 must be in field1 or field2 or fieldN) AND (termN must be in field1 or field2 or fieldN). If one search term is not present in any of the field, the query return 0. Isn't that that you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_terms = explode(' ', $search_text);
foreach ($search_terms as $search_term) 
{
    $conditions[] = ['OR' => [
        'cohortes.titre LIKE' => '%' . $search_term . '%',
        'cohortes.code LIKE' => '%' . $search_term . '%',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.